# problem playing videos, from youtube any browser, from mpv (lubuntu 18.04)

Tags: sound, lubuntu, 18.04, video, youtube

OS: Lubuntu 18.04 updated to 2018-06-25

Hardware: exo cloudbok e15

(note: english is not my native languaje)

Pasted at the end the result of lshw.

Symptoms:

- youtube in firefox 60.0.2: keeps showing buffer animation.
- youtube in chromium 66.0.3359: keeps in a loop of buffering a lot, playing seconds at high speed, and so on.
- gnome mpv: don't works at all
- vlc: plays fine, but no sound.

I've tested ALL imaginable version. All flavors of ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 16.04 with different kind of problems.

In Ubuntu 16.04 video works fine, but no sound, and the wifi chip is not recognized.

I frankly threw the towel. I have no idea of what's going on, aside that the notebook is what's thecnically known as a 'pile of crap'. Sadly, I haven't this kind of problems since 2015.

```
lshw:
`cloudbooke15
    descripción: Notebook
    producto: CloudbookE15 (5859-6646)
    fabricante: EXO
    versión: Type1 - TBD by OEM
    serie: HBG4e667A5C6C
    anchura: 64 bits
    capacidades: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuración: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Cloudbook sku=5859-6646 uuid=6C5C7A66-D0C8-BD45-909F-54EA5FBD3D97
  *-core
       descripción: Placa base
       producto: N141C
       fabricante: EXO
       id físico: 0
       versión: Type2 - Board Version
       serie: Type2 - Board Serial Number
       ranura: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          descripción: BIOS
          fabricante: INSYDE Corp.
          id físico: 0
          versión: EXO9x.WT314P.NJNJREN03
          date: 02/16/2017
          tamaño: 64KiB
          capacidad: 3008KiB
          capacidades: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb zipboot biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          descripción: CPU
          producto: Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8350  CPU @ 1.44GHz
          fabricante: Intel Corp.
          id físico: 4
          información del bus: cpu@0
          versión: Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8350  CPU @ 1.44GHz
          serie: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          ranura: CHV
          tamaño: 493MHz
          capacidad: 1920MHz
          anchura: 64 bits
          reloj: 83MHz
          capacidades: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat cpufreq
          configuración: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             descripción: L1 caché
             id físico: 6
             ranura: L1 Cache
             tamaño: 32KiB
             capacidad: 32KiB
             capacidades: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuración: level=1
        *-cache:1
             descripción: L2 caché
             id físico: 7
             ranura: L2 Cache
             tamaño: 1MiB
             capacidad: 1MiB
             capacidades: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuración: level=2
     *-cache
          descripción: L1 caché
          id físico: 5
          ranura: L1 Cache
          tamaño: 24KiB
          capacidad: 24KiB
          capacidades: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuración: level=1
     *-memory
          descripción: Memoria de sistema
          id físico: 17
          ranura: Placa de sistema o placa base
          tamaño: 2GiB
        *-bank
             descripción: DIMM DDR3 Síncrono 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)
             fabricante: 0000
             id físico: 0
             serie: 00000000
             ranura: ChannelA-DIMM0
             tamaño: 2GiB
             anchura: 16 bits
             reloj: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-pci
          descripción: Host bridge
          producto: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
          fabricante: Intel Corporation
          id físico: 100
          información del bus: pci@0000:00:00.0
          versión: 36
          anchura: 32 bits
          reloj: 33MHz
          configuración: driver=iosf_mbi_pci
          recursos: irq:0
        *-display
             descripción: VGA compatible controller
             producto: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 2
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
             versión: 36
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
             recursos: irq:119 memoria:90000000-90ffffff memoria:80000000-8fffffff ioport:1000(size=64) memoria:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia NO RECLAMADO
             descripción: Multimedia controller
             producto: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 3
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:03.0
             versión: 36
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuración: latency=0
             recursos: memoria:91000000-913fffff
        *-generic:0
             descripción: Signal processing controller
             producto: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: b
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:0b.0
             versión: 36
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             recursos: irq:123 memoria:91818000-91818fff
        *-usb
             descripción: USB controller
             producto: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 14
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:14.0
             versión: 36
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             recursos: irq:117 memoria:91800000-9180ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                producto: xHCI Host Controller
                fabricante: Linux 4.15.0-23-generic xhci-hcd
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: usb@1
                nombre lógico: usb1
                versión: 4.15
                capacidades: usb-2.00
                configuración: driver=hub slots=7 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   descripción: Vídeo
                   producto: USB 2.0 Camera
                   fabricante: Alcor Micro, Corp.
                   id físico: 3
                   información del bus: usb@1:3
                   versión: 0.03
                   capacidades: usb-2.00
                   configuración: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   descripción: Teclado
                   producto: USB KEYBOARD
                   fabricante: SINO WEALTH
                   id físico: 4
                   información del bus: usb@1:4
                   versión: 1.05
                   capacidades: usb-2.00
                   configuración: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                producto: xHCI Host Controller
                fabricante: Linux 4.15.0-23-generic xhci-hcd
                id físico: 1
                información del bus: usb@2
                nombre lógico: usb2
                versión: 4.15
                capacidades: usb-3.00
                configuración: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   descripción: Dispositivo de almacenamiento masivo
                   producto: Elements 10B8
                   fabricante: Western Digital
                   id físico: 1
                   información del bus: usb@2:1
                   nombre lógico: scsi0
                   versión: 10.12
                   serie: 57583231414334355938534E
                   capacidades: usb-3.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuración: driver=usb-storage maxpower=896mA speed=5000Mbit/s
                 *-disk
                      descripción: SCSI Disk
                      producto: Elements 10B8
                      fabricante: WD
                      id físico: 0.0.0
                      información del bus: scsi@0:0.0.0
                      nombre lógico: /dev/sda
                      versión: 1012
                      serie: WX21AC45Y8SN
                      tamaño: 931GiB (1TB)
                      capacidades: partitioned partitioned:dos
                      configuración: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=b49bca55
                    *-volume
                         descripción: partición EXT4
                         fabricante: Linux
                         id físico: 1
                         información del bus: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                         nombre lógico: /dev/sda1
                         nombre lógico: /media/monica/usbdisk4
                         versión: 1.0
                         serie: a518917d-8e86-4a75-8ccb-58325d122ab5
                         tamaño: 931GiB
                         capacidad: 931GiB
                         capacidades: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                         configuración: created=2015-05-17 17:11:05 filesystem=ext4 label=usbdisk4 lastmountpoint=/media/monica/usbdisk4 modified=2018-06-25 17:12:41 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2018-06-25 17:12:41 state=mounted
        *-generic:1
             descripción: Encryption controller
             producto: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1a
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             versión: 36
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=mei_txe latency=0
             recursos: irq:122 memoria:91700000-917fffff memoria:91600000-916fffff
        *-isa
             descripción: ISA bridge
             producto: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1f
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             versión: 36
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             recursos: irq:0
  *-battery
       descripción: Ion litio Battery
       producto: SR Real Battery
       fabricante: Intel SR 1
       id físico: 1
       versión: Date
       serie: 123456789
       ranura: I2C2
       configuración: voltage=3,8V
  *-power NO RECLAMADO
       descripción: OEM Define 1
       producto: OEM Define 5
       fabricante: OEM Define 2
       id físico: 2
       versión: OEM Define 6
       serie: OEM Define 3
       capacidad: 42mWh
  *-network
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       id físico: 3
       nombre lógico: wlan0
       serie: 88:83:5d:3b:b8:f6
       capacidades: ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs ip=192.168.0.102 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn`
```

Comment: update: while "playing" a youtube video on firefox, the process "pulseaudio" surges to 100% usage of cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ubuntu 16.04 , and Intel GPU Official drivers ,
[Intel Graphics tool](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb)

Comment: Can you expand this a little more?